# Thread main stopped before call to println()?

Tags: java

the issue now is if your run my program at out put I should have a string output of user entry for monthly investment, interest rate, and year and it should print it in one line and the next line and after that should be the same but diffrent values if the user entred he wanted to enter another different values for monthly investment, interest rate, and year. my prible is it prints everything into just one like ex:$400 2.0% 3 $500 3.0% 2 <--- this starting from $500 should be in the next line not first with the first entry??

```
System.out.print("Inv/Mo.\tRate\tYears\tFuture Value\n");
     for (int j = 0; j < FutureValueArrayList.size(); j++)
     {
        String myArrayList = FutureValueArrayList.get(j);
        System.out.print(ArrayList + "\t");
        System.out.println();

     }
```

i also get this error i can't seem to figure a way to fix it "Thread main stopped before call to println()" which is the println after the print(ArrayList + "\t"); on the my for loop.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class FutureValueApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // display a welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator");
    System.out.println();

    ArrayList<String> FutureValueArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // perform 1 or more calculations
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        // get the input from the user
        System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
        double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
        double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 30);
        int years = getIntWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);

        // calculate the future value
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12/100;
        int months = years * 12;
        double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
            monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

        // get the currency and percent formatters
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        percent.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

        // format the result as a single string
        String results =
              "Monthly investment:\t"
                  + currency.format(monthlyInvestment) + "\n"
            + "Yearly interest rate:\t"
                  + percent.format(interestRate/100) + "\n"
            + "Number of years:\t"
                  +  years + "\n"
            + "Future value:\t\t"
                  + currency.format(futureValue) + "\n";

        // print the results
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
        System.out.println(results);

      String monthlyInvestmentFormat = currency.format(monthlyInvestment);
      String interestRateFormat = percent.format(interestRate/100);
      String futureValueFormat = currency.format(futureValue);

      FutureValueArrayList.add(monthlyInvestmentFormat);
      FutureValueArrayList.add(interestRateFormat);
      FutureValueArrayList.add(Integer.toString(years));
      FutureValueArrayList.add(futureValueFormat);




        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();

        System.out.println();
    }

     System.out.print("Inv/Mo.\tRate\tYears\tFuture Value\n");
     for (int j = 0; j < FutureValueArrayList.size(); j++)
     {
        String ArrayList = FutureValueArrayList.get(j);
        System.out.print(ArrayList + "\t");
        System.out.println();

     }
    System.out.println();
}   

public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    boolean isValid = false;
    double d = 0;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextDouble())
        {
            d = sc.nextDouble();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    }
    return d;
}

public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
double min, double max)
{
    double d = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
        if (d <= min)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        else if (d >= max)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        else
            isValid = true;
    }
    return d;
}

public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    boolean isValidInt = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (isValidInt == false)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            isValidInt = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    }
    return i;
}

public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
int min, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        i = getInt(sc, prompt);
        if (i <= min)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        else if (i >= max)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        else
            isValid = true;
    }
    return i;
}

public static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyInvestment,
double monthlyInterestRate, int months)
{
    double futureValue = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
    {
        futureValue =
            (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) *
            (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
    }
    return futureValue;
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the error? PS: Naming variables after native classes is really.. really confusing!

Comment: Also, as a coding clarity convention, the first character of a variable name should be a lower case letter.  Naming a string "ArrayList" is absurdly confusing.

Comment: @nickecarlo It doesn't throw up any Syntax errors. Just tried it.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a class in `java.util` package.. You should use other name as `String` variable.

Comment: I ran the code. It seems to  be working fine. IS the issue occouring after some specific number of data entries?

Comment: @ChrisCooney Yup realized that as I hit Add Comment. That's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: the issue is if your run my program at out put I should have a string output of user entry for monthly investment, interest rate, and year and it should print it in one line and the next line and after that should be the same but diffrent values if the user entred he wanted to enter another different values for monthly investment, interest rate, and year. my prible is it prints everything into just one like ex:$400 2.0% 3 $500 3.0% 2 <--- this starting from $500 should be in the next line not first with the first entry??

Comment: I hope the answer below addressed whatever it was you were asking because I really can't understand what you're writing there.

Comment: what? why don't make a multi diemonsional array of string ?
for all columns and rows ? and then each cell will hold
the relative user data of specific column..

Comment: @nickecarlo, haha I know I've been trying to wrap my head around it for so long I can't seem to explain it well. the answer below does answer my question though

Comment: your edit is not readable .. sorry, please edit again and make it more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to code like this

```
 System.out.print("Inv/Mo.\tRate\tYears\tFuture Value\n");
 for (int j = 0; j < FutureValueArrayList.size(); j++)
 {
    String ArrayList = FutureValueArrayList.get(j);
    System.out.print(ArrayList + "\t");
    if((j+1)%4 == 0){
        System.out.println();
    }

 }
System.out.println();
```

Notice the use of (j+1)%4 trick.

Note: This is just a formatting hack. The proper way to go about doing this would be to create a FutureValue object with 4 parameters (rate, sum, time, futureValue) and overriding the toString() method for properly printing the object in required format.
I encourage you to try this.

Approach 2:

```
/*FutureValueArrayList.add(monthlyInvestmentFormat);
            FutureValueArrayList.add(interestRateFormat);
            FutureValueArrayList.add(Integer.toString(years));
            FutureValueArrayList.add(futureValueFormat);*/

            FutureValueArrayList.add(monthlyInvestmentFormat+"\t"+interestRateFormat+"\t"+Integer.toString(years)+"\t"+futureValueFormat);
```

Now there is no need to change your printing code in any way.

Comment: is there another way of doing it that is similar to my for loop?

Comment: I can suggest another way. You have four FutureValueArrayList.add() for every single line. Instead of that just have one FutureValueArrayList.add(Combined String). Will update my answer to demonstrate this.